# Multiple selection ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, mvvm

I have two ListView controls. On the left side i display a list of countries and the right side displays a corresponding list of cities.
Now for the problem: I want to populate a third ListView with a list of selected Cities. I already figured out a way to not add a city multiple times, but i still have the problem of adding selected cities for a country that is no longer selected.
For example:

- Select USA -> Select New York & Miami
- Select Germany -> Select Berlin & Munich

When i press "Add" i just want to add the cities from the currently selected country, in this case Berlin & Munich.

Parts of the View so far:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CountryList, Mode=TwoWay}"
           SelectionMode="Single"
           SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCountry, Mode=TwoWay}">
               <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                     </DataTemplate>
               </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<...>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding CityList, Mode=TwoWay}"
          SelectionMode="Extended">
          <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding isSelected}"/>
                </Style>
          </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
             <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding AddedCities}">
     <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <...>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

My ViewModel implements the following (and more) properties:

```
public Country SelectedCountry
        {
            get { return GetValue(() => SelectedCountry); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(() => SelectedCountry, value);

                var query = from c in CityList
                            where c.Country == SelectedCountry
                            select c;

                CitiesInCountry= new ObservableCollection<City>(query);
            }
        }

public IEnumerable<City> SelectedCities { get { return CityList.Where(x => x.IsSelected); } }
```

This probably isn't the best way to tackle the problem but i'm still learning.
How and when do i reset the selected cities? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. It works for my case and sometimes the most obvious answers are those we think of last.

```
public IEnumerable<City> SelectedCities{ get { return CityList.Where(x => x.IsSelected && x.Country == SelectedCountry); } }
```

This does not prevent the selection of multiple cities for different countries simultaneously but suppresses those who are not of the selected country.